# Animated Circle Border around Image?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm trying to animate a circle around an image, but my coding makes the image spin along with the circle border, is there any way to stop the image from spinning but keep the border spinning? help please.

```
.sidebar img { position:absolute; left:105px; top:30px; width:110px; height:110px; border-radius:50%; -webkit-filter:grayscale(0%); border-radius:50%; border:10px solid c5c6cc ; border:10px dashed #c49683; animation-name: spinning-circle;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
   outline-color: #EA3556;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px yellow;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinning-circle {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
```

Comment: no need to separate the element, you can apply the opposite animation to the image, example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51010685/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate spinner and image element like below,

```css
img {
    position: relative;
    left: 107px;
    top: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
}
.image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 105px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid c5c6cc;
    border: 10px dashed #c49683;
    animation-name: spinning-circle;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    outline-color: #EA3556;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px yellow;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinning-circle {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
</div>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
```