# How do i rotate the image without rotating the division

Tags: html, css, css-animations

**I want to animate rotation of the gradient color without rotating the rhombus.**

I tried using `transform: rotate` but it also rotated the shape.
Is there a way to do so?

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% -50%);
}

#shape {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/PjxzdmcgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMSAxIiBwcmVzZXJ2ZUFzcGVjdFJhdGlvPSJub25lIj48bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9Imxlc3NoYXQtZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMzYWNmZDUiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMTAwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzNhNGVkNSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+PC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD48cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2xlc3NoYXQtZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz48L3N2Zz4=);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  top: -250px;
  left: -250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="shape"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can create pseudo element inside of your `#shape` that will have gradient as background instead of `#shape`. Then rotate this pseudo element

Comment: An easy way to this is by using native CSS gradients instead of a background image. You can animate the gradient's direction via javascript then.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51010556/8620333 (simply add the animation to only the pseudo element)

Answer (score 1):

If you put a pseudo element on the box, positioned absolutely, you can rotate that 'behind' the box without it disturbing anything else:

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% -50%);
}

#shape::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, yellow);
  animation: rotate 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359.9deg);
  }
}

#shape {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  top: -250px;
  left: -250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="shape"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:before` pseudo element

```css
.box {
height: 100vh;
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
}

#shape {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
}

#shape::before {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TIMER</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div id="shape"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

But you could also just use a `linear-gradient`

```css
.box {
height: 100vh;
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
}

#shape {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(30deg, #53fdfd, navy)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TIMER</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div id="shape"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```